# Widening conversion from array to Object (java)

Tags: java

Why is this type of conversion(array to Object) possible in Java  and what does x refer to ?(can I still access the array elements "s1","s2","s3" through x). Where is the array to Object conversion used?

```
String[] array = {"s1","s2","s3"};  
 Object x = array;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *widening reference conversion* ([JLS Section 5.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)).  `x` still refers to the array, but Java only knows `x` as an `Object`.

You cannot access the array elements directly through `x` unless you cast it back to `String[]` first.

Comment: I would only use this conversion when I had to place such a `String[]` into a collection (or another array) of `Objects` that was meant to contain such heterogeneous items whose only commonality is that they're all `Objects`.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible because an `Array` **is** an `Object`. When you do this widening conversion, you tell Java "This is an `Object` and you don't need to know anything else about it." You won't be able to access the array elements anymore , because plain `Object`s don't support element access. However, you can **cast** `x` back to an array, which would let you access its elements again:

```
String[] array = {"s1","s2","s3"};  
Object x = array;

// These will print out the same memory address, 
// because they point to the same object in memory
System.out.println(array);
System.out.println(x);

// This doesn't compile, because x is **only** an Object:
//System.out.println(x[0]);

// Cast x to a String[] (or Object[]) to access its elements.
String[] theSameArray = (String[]) x;
System.out.println(theSameArray[0]); // prints s1
System.out.println(((Object[]) x)[0]); // prints s1
```

Answer (score 1):

Every array type in Java ultimately is a kind of `Object`. There is no conversion going on here; it's just the usual ability to assign a subtype value to a supertype variable.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have pointed out that arrays extend `Object`. To answer your last question:

> Where is the array to Object conversion used?

This would rarely be used, but one use case is related to [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Consider this method:

```
static void count(Object... objects) {
    System.out.println("There are " + objects.length + " object(s).");
}
```

In order to treat a single array argument as an element of the varags, you would need to cast to `Object`:

```
String[] strings = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};

count(strings);         //There are 3 object(s).
count((Object)strings); //There are 1 object(s).
```

This is because a varargs parameter is an array first and foremost, so when it's ambiguous the compiler treats an array parameter that way. Upcasting to `Object` tells the compiler otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

in your code x is a pointer to an array of String which names array.

so what ever you change in array would happen to the x too, but it seems to be useless , because Object is a super class for String[] so wherever you should use Object you can use String[].